# Pass String parameter with doubles quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs3

Please help me how to pass a string(which i cannot edit, like coming from DB) with double quotes to a method in the javascript.

***Please note this "Hello "world", Welcome..." is coming from DB which i cannot edit. To understand you easily how the format is coming i placed it here like this**

```
var tempString = "Hello "world", Welcome...";
sampleMethod(tempString);
sampleMethod : function(tempString)
{
  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspalert(tempString)<br>
}
```

Actually i was working on this thing in the `EXtjs 3.4` Grouping View for Grouping Store.

Pelase help me with this.

Comment: wrap it in single quotes ?

Comment: perhaps you should explain what happens when you try to pass the string to your js function?

Comment: Can you show us the code that receives this string?

Comment: @Swifty add explained in the question i was doing this in the extjs.
I am passing object directly through javascript code to extjs method, it is taking the object as "[object Object]" in the parameter. This is giving me the error.

Comment: I guess Frits wants to see the actual code, where you create this object, since if you can read something to a JS variable, you are  supposed to able to edit it too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quotes to wrap the string.

```
var tempString = 'Hello "world", Welcome...';
```

Or you could escape the inner double quotes with `&#34;` (Depending on the use of the string)

Or you could regular expressions to change the string from the database. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516786/how-do-i-replace-a-double-quote-with-an-escape-char-double-quote-in-a-string-usi)

Comment: "`Please note this "Hello "world", Welcome..." is coming from DB which i cannot edit.`".

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape the quotes

```
var tempString = "Hello \"world\", Welcome...";
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3awCH/)** 
If the string in the DB can't be changed manually. Use single quotes instead.

```
var tempString = 'Hello "world", Welcome...';
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to change this specific string:

```
var tempString = "Hello \"world\", Welcome...";

var result = tempString.replace(/([^"]*)\"(\w*)\"([^"]*)/, "$1\'$2\'$3")
```

`result` should be "Hello 'world', Welcome...".

So you can call method

```
sampleMethod(tempString.replace(/([^"]*)\"(\w*)\"([^"]*)/, "$1\'$2\'$3"));
```

And if there is space in the world:

```
var tempString = "Hello \"wo r ld\", Welcome...";
```

this replacement is better:

```
var result = tempString.replace(/([^"]*)\"([\w\s]*)\"([^"]*)/, "$1\'$2\'$3")
```

Comment: BTW, this solution is adopted from [Regex for single quote within single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672629/regex-for-single-quote-within-single-quotes)

Comment: Even though your solution is helping me upto 100%, with the reference of your solution i made my thing work. Thank you